# Suggest a better way to make online coding contest website

Tags: php, javascript

i want to develop a online coding contest website on which a user select a programming

language(c,c++,java) then writes it's code and then click on compile and it's code get

compiled and the output will be shown(with errors if any)?

so **my question** is that:

is there any existing framework or a already developed solution  from which i can get help

in compilation of my code online?

i am using PHP,mysql and javascript.

Comment: Basically i want a solution for compilation of my code online

Comment: You don't want this... You do not want people running java/c/c++ on your server... Unless you like your server to be hacked to hell and back.

Comment: You should add a tag for your operating system, the solutions will be very OS-dependent.

Comment: an alternative to what BGerrissen said is to sandbox it, by using for instance [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) (on Unix, if possible) and a special sandbox user with minimal permissions - then people who tried to execute malicious code would do minimal harm to the server

Comment: Just making sure Peeyush realizes what he's getting into ;) security should be high priority on this one.

Comment: BGerrissen: He doesn't say he intends to run the code, only compile it.

Comment: Thanks for you answers,i know the all risk but i am just trying it on my localhost so their is not a security issue...that's why i am asking that how i implement this,so suggest me solution about it and one more think is that i am Using UBUNTU 10.04

Answer (score 6):

You should look at [Codepad](http://codepad.org/)

Their About page lists some details of how they achieve the site: http://codepad.org/about

Answer (score 1):

You have several options: 
 1.  use [ideone api](http://ideone.com)
 2.  use external, ready made widgets (like [scarky](http://scarky.com)) 
 3.  use an online judge facility which supports private contests like [SPOJ](http://spoj.pl).